# What is incorrect with my first-order predicate calculus?

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm trying to write the FOL for "Borrowing a book doesn’t change who owns it" given the functions:

- Book(x) = x is a book
- Owns(x, y) = x owns y
- Provide(x, y) = x provides y

My attempt was ∀x,y (Book(x) ∧ Owns(y, x) ∧ Provides(y, x)) ⇒ Owns(y, x)
but I'm not quite sure what I am missing from this

Comment: If you're talking about change, you'll need to get time involved somehow. Maybe have an owns_at_time(x,y,t) predicate? It may help to elaborate on what context this problem came up in (e.g. if it's for a class, what similar formulas have shown up?)

Comment: @TomKern we weren't given a time function and were only given the 3 formulas above for the problem so I'm not quite sure how the temporal aspect could be expressed

Comment: Google with quotation marks the given statement. The search results seem relevant.

Comment: You're closing the bracket too early so the variables in the consequent of the implication are outside the scope of the universal quantifiers.